# Forms-angular, how a custom directive field can affect the $pristine state of the full record?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, mongoose

Question related to [forms-angular](http://www.forms-angular.org/) project.

### Preamble

The default `formInput` directive of forms-angular can be override by a custom directive by specifying the `form.directive` property in an extended mongoose model,

```
var CategorySchema = new Schema({
    name: String,
});


var PlansSchema = new Schema({
    categories: {
        type: [CategorySchema],
        form: {
            directive: 'plan-categories'
        }
    }
});
```

The custom `plan-categories` directive has a template where fields of `[CategorySchema]` can be edited.

### What is working

Let's start with a first simple template:

```
<div>
    <div ng-repeat="category in record.categories">
        <input ng-model="category.name" />
    </div>
</div>
```

Forms-angular can successfully detect changes in these custom `plan-categories` directive input fields bound to data (injected scope.record). In particular when changing the user changes the value of the above input fields, the "Save" button of the page is enabled, allowing the Save operation.

The activation of the Save button thanks to the following comparison in parent formInput's BaseCtrl scope `false === $scope[$scope.topLevelFormName].$pristine` (see [base.js](https://github.com/forms-angular/forms-angular/blob/master/js/controllers/base.js#L956)).

### Not working

Now, the Save button doesn't get enabled, when changing the category.name variable with an expression or a function called by ng-click, as below:

```
<div>
    <div ng-repeat="category in record.categories">
        <input ng-model="category.name" />
        <button ng-click="category.name = 'Hello'">Edit</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

On button click, the category.name variable seems to be correctly changed, since the value in the input is changed accordingly. Unfortunately, the Save button stays disabled.

Note: I also unsuccessfully tried to pass to ng-click a method (from the scope injected in the `link` method of the custom directive) and setting the `category.name` variable in a $timeout call.

I guess the `ng-model` directive of the input field calls parent's (multi-ancestor?) $setDirty() method.

### Question

- how do I *magically* get $setDirty() called by forms-angular in order to enable the "Save" button

If it is not possible:

- how do I access BaseCtrl scope and call $setDirty() when changing the `record.categories` elements?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Offhand I cannot think of a magical solution, but the decidedly non-magical way is to depend on $data.baseScope (see https://github.com/forms-angular/forms-angular/blob/master/js/controllers/base.js#L12) which saves going through lots of $parents.

Comment: It seems that $data.baseScope is undefined at the time the button is ng-clicked. In the directive link method, doing a `console.log($data.baseScope)` is fine (browser console delay), but doing at the same place a `$data.baseScope.$setDirty()` fails because `$data.baseScope`is undefined.

Comment: By looking at `setFormDirty()` code of BaseCtrl scope, I can enable the Save button with `element.inheritedData('$formController').$setDirty()` where element is an argument of the link function of the directive. Does it sound good practice?

Comment: Seems to be.  I can't think what would change to stop it working, and it is quite elegant and not too bad efficiency wise.